# Eureka - unable to send heartbeat

Tags: netflix-eureka

I am using `Netflix Eureka` to implement a service registry for my microservice. However when I tried to deploy the `eureka-server.war` in my `Tomcat` server, it keeps throwing the below error in the logs :

```
2017-03-08 04:44:47,982 WARN  com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient:127 [DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0] [execute] Request execution failure with status code 404; retrying on another server if available
2017-03-08 04:44:47,984 WARN  com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient:127 [DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0] [execute] Request execution failure with status code 404; retrying on another server if available
2017-03-08 04:44:47,984 ERROR com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient:934 [DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0] [fetchRegistry] DiscoveryClient_EUREKA/{my hostname here} - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1013)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndUpdateDelta(DiscoveryClient.java:1055)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:929)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1451)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1418)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I can't seem to find how to fix this error, nor why this error occurs in the first place.

Please help me on successfully fixing this issue. I think this might be related to some https/proxy issues. But I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your server acts as a client. Make sure you use the right annotation (if you use spring boot)